# Teradata - How to replace special characters?

Tags: regex, teradata

In Teradata how to replace SUB ? symbol.

i tried below query , still it is showing.

```
select OTRANSLATE(OTRANSLATE(OTRANSLATE(col, X'0D' , ' ') , X'0A' , ' '),X'01A',' ')
```

Note : in the notepad , it is showing different way.
[image]

Comment: Is this Teradata or Oracle? If Teradata, is "col" typed as CHARACTER SET LATIN or CHARACTER SET UNICODE?  Presuming it's Teradata and CHARACTER SET LATIN, you can use `OREPLACE(col,CHR(13)||CHR(10)||CHR(26),CHR(32)||CHR(32)||CHR(32))`. Using CHR which returns CHARACTER SET LATIN to keep all the arguments of the same character set is the trick to avoiding "untranslatable character" errors.

Comment: the column type is "CHARACTER SET UNICODE CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL" and tried with OREPLACE(col_name,CHR(32)||CHR(10)||CHR(26),'') code. i am getting Failed 6706 : The String contains an untranslatable character

Comment: For Unicode you need `oTranslate(col_name, x'0A0D'||TRANSLATE(CHR(26) USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE WITH ERROR),'abc')`

Comment: Try `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[^[:print:]]+', '');`

Comment: Yes, to supply UNICODE U+001A (which is not valid in Teradata server UNICODE character set) you either need `TRANSLATE(CHR(26) USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE WITH ERROR)` or if you activate "Unicode Pass-Through" feature for a UTF8 or UTF16 session, then you can specify literal value as`U&'#001A' UESCAPE '#'` or  `_UNICODE '001A'xc`

Comment: BTW - the "x" as prefix for hex character literals is not a documented feature for Teradata (though it often works). The "xc" suffix is the documented Teradata-specific syntax, along with the more standard Unicode delimited literal syntax with "U&" prefix and UESCAPE for entering hex values.

Comment: I tried this option : REGEXP_REPLACE(cols,'[^\x20-\x7e]+', ' ', 1, 0, 'i')..now it is working as expected. also I tried the above all option..But result is not expected one.Can someone help me how this fix is working - ,'[^\x20-\x7e]+'